# Why is detergent better at cleaning than soap?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Soaps and detergent are both molecules that have a polar head and a long organic tail. In Soaps, the head is often a carboxylate ion $\ce{COO-}$ where as a detergent has a benzosulphonate $\ce{C6H11SO3-}$(or other) head:

[image]

I have often seen that detergents are 'stronger' than soaps. Why is this? It is given as the reason why we don't wash our skin with detergents. The only answer I could find is that detergents don't form insoluble salts with Mg and Ca (scum) but doesn't seem like it would have a large impact. So why are detergents stronger than soaps?

Comment: Actually one of the advantage of detergents is right that they are less aggressive (pH) to the skin than soaps. Bath shower and hairs formulations are detergents. Still, all the pros that comes to my mind are not due to cleansing power. If there are regular differences (the process has multiple steps or facets) likely someone will answer.

Comment: hm, if you wouldn't mind, could you describe the pros? I haven't heard of many except being 'stronger' which apparently isn't even true!

Comment: The pH of anionic detergents is less alkaline than that of soap, so they are better for skin and especially hairs. This is because benzensulphonic ac. is stronger than fatty acids. Those detergents should be in standard body shower formulation. Tough we are speaking of formulations that might contain more or have changed. The others are as you and especially the answer so mentions are linked to water hardness and mass production.